# NotificationManager.notify does not create a notification in one app, despite the exact same coding working in another app

Tags: android

I am simultaneously developing two Android applications that are communicating with each other, and I am using notifications to show received messages. This is the code I am using to show a notification:

```
private void showNotification(String title, String content) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                "NOTIF_CHANNEL",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("CHANNEL FOR INFORMING ABOUT MESSAGE RECEIVED");
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "default")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle(title) // title for notification
            .setContentText(content)// message for notification
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI) // set alarm sound for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
    Intent intent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName())
            .setPackage(null)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

In one of my applications, this works flawlessly every time, but in the other it never works. I am using the exact same code and running the applications on the same device.

I am curious as to if someone is able to identify or make a guess on factors that would make a difference here. I have tried using the same icon, title, content, and sound, but to no avail. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the same support library version and using same targetSdkVersion in both apps?

Comment: I wasn't using the same support library version... Turns out I hade to use a version newer than the targetSdkVersion, but now it works. Thank you so much, feels like something I probably should've checked. Now I know!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post it as an answer in order to help users with same problem to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working in one app but not in the other, and the code is exactly the same, surely you are using distinct versions of support library and/or distinct targetSdkVersion. Set the same of the app which works in the other that doesn't works.